# Not able to display Multiple string in visualforce page from controller

Tags: apex, soql, list, string, array

I have a Multiple Product and each has it's own UnitPrice

i am just passing it to String variable and store it inside the for loop but not sure How to display each of them in visualforce page

[image]

here is my code :

```
public void retrieveBundleInfo() {
    bundlewithProduct = [SELECT Id, (select Id, Name, Product__c, Product__r.ProductCode, Product__r.Description, Quantity__c from Product_Quantities__r) FROM Bundle__c WHERE Id =: QBP.Bundle__c];
    PQList1 = [Select Product__c, Bundle__c, Quantity__c, Discount__c, Product__r.ProductCode, Product__r.Description from Product_Quantity__c where Bundle__c =: bundlewithProduct];
    set<String> setPB = new set<String>();
    for(Integer i=0;i<PQList1.size(); i++){
        for(PriceBookEntry pe : [SELECT Id, Product2Id, UnitPrice FROM PriceBookEntry where Product2Id =: PQList1.get(i).product__c]){
            try {
               ListPrice = String.ValueOf(pe.UnitPrice);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Visualforce code :

```
<apex:variable value="" var="foo" rendered="{!IF(lstSections2 = True, true, false)}" >
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Select Bundle" >
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:actionRegion >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!QBP}" var="Q">
        <apex:column headerValue="Select Bundle">
        <apex:inputField value="{!Q.Bundle__c}">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="relatedBundleInfo" action="{!retrieveBundleInfo}" immediate="false"/>
        </apex:inputField>
        </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        <apex:pageblockSection id="relatedBundleInfo">
            <apex:repeat value="{!bundlewithProduct}" var="bp">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!PQList1}" var="bwithp">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Product Name">
                        <apex:outputField value="{!bwithp.Product__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Quantity">
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!bwithp.Quantity__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Part Number">
                    <apex:pageBlockSection >
                        <apex:outputText value="{!bwithp.Product__r.ProductCode}" label="Part Number :"/>
                        <apex:outputText value="{!bwithp.Product__r.Description}" label="Description :"/>
                        <apex:outputText value="{!ListPrice}" label="List Price :"/>
                        <apex:outputText value="{!ListPrice}" label="Sale Price :"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageblocksection>
    </apex:actionRegion>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</li>
</apex:variable>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53221/discussion-on-question-by-wanttobeacoder-not-able-to-display-multiple-string-in).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you want to filter the PriceBookEntries as you could potentially have multiple entries for a single Product2. I will leave that part up to you.

**Note** It is late so there may be some errors, general debugging may be required

```
public void retrieveBundleInfo() {
    bundlewithProduct = [SELECT Id, (select Id, Name, Product__c, Bundle__c, Quantity__c, Discount__c, Product__r.ProductCode, Product__r.Description, Quantity__c from Product_Quantities__r) FROM Bundle__c WHERE Id = :QBP.Bundle__c];
    set<String> prodIds = new set<String>();

    for (Bundle__c b : bundlewithProduct) {
        for (Product_Quantities__c pq : b.Product_Quantities__r)
            prodIds.add(b.Product__c);
    }

    Map<Id, PricebookEntry[]> bToPBE = New Map<Id, PricebookEntry[]>();

    for (PriceBookEntry pe : [SELECT Id, Product2Id, UnitPrice FROM PriceBookEntry where Product2Id = :prodIds]) {
        PricebookEntry[] pbeList = bToPBE.get(pe.Product2Id);
        if (peList == null) pbeList = New PricebookEntry[]{};
        pbeList.add(pe);
        bToPBE.put(pe.Product2Id, pbeList);
    }
}
```

Basically:

1. Get List of bundles with subquery
2. Grab all Product__c (Product2Id) from the subqueries
3. Query PBE and place the entries in a map with the Product2Id as the key

You could narrow it down more or use as is to display on your VF page keeping in mind to do proper error checking and ensuring that all keys exist as VF is not very forgiving when map keys do not exist.

You may be best served to refactor this into a wrapper class as well.

Or after some sleep I may have a better solution....